# google People API error code: 400, Invalid JSON payload received

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api

Hi guys am working on a projet the uses google people API to do crud operation on an authentiated user using nodejs and express server.

I was able to get all contacts, search for a particular contact and using the resoureName.

but i'm unable to create contact group or label. i have read google documentation for weeks, i am having error

here isresponse from the server

```
                    ^
```

GaxiosError: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "contactGroup[name]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'contactGroup[name]' could not be found in request message.    at Gaxios. (D:#001ADeveloperZone\workSpaces\autmarket\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:73:27)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (D:#001ADeveloperZone\workSpaces\autmarket\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:16:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
response: {
config: {
access_token: ',
refresh_token: '',
url: 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups?contactGroup%5Bname%5D=hotmail',
method: 'POST',
paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
headers: {
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)',
Authorization: '',
Accept: 'application/json'
},
params: [Object: null prototype] { contactGroup: { name: 'hotmail' } },
validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
responseType: 'json'
},
data: {
error: {
code: 400,
message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "contactGroup[name]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'contactGroup[name]' could not be found in request message.`,
errors: [
{
message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "contactGroup[name]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'contactGroup[name]' could not be found in request message.`,
reason: 'invalid'
}
],
status: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
details: [
{
'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest',
fieldViolations: [Array]
}
]
}
},
headers: {
'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
'cache-control': 'private',
connection: 'close',
'content-encoding': 'gzip',
'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
date: 'Tue, 08 Mar 2022 16:27:38 GMT',
server: 'ESF',
'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
'x-xss-protection': '0'
},
status: 400,
statusText: 'Bad Request'
},
config: {
access_token: ,
refresh_token: '',
url: 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups?contactGroup%5Bname%5D=hotmail',
method: 'POST',
paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
headers: {
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)',
Authorization: '',
Accept: 'application/json'
},
params: [Object: null prototype] { contactGroup: { name: 'hotmail' } },
validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
responseType: 'json'
},
code: 400,
errors: [
{
message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "contactGroup[name]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'contactGroup[name]' could not be found in request message.`,
reason: 'invalid'
}
]
}

here is my code

```
create_group: (req, res) => {
try {
  //create group or label
  let userGoogleContactsGroups = getGroups().then((data) =>
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  );
  let userGroups = userGoogleContactsGroups.then(({ contactGroups }) => {
    let names = contactGroups.map((group) => `${group.name}`);
    return names;
  });

  userGroups.then((data) => {
    if (data.includes("amazoggn")) {
      return res.status(301).json({ code: 301, mesage: "group exist" });
    } else {
      // let name =" amazoggn";
      try {     
      
          contactGroup={
            name:name 
          }
        
       let strdata  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({contactGroup}));

  

        let mydata = people.contactGroups.create(strdata)
        if (mydata) {
          console.log(mydata)
        } else {
          return "error occured"
        }
    
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

}

please I need help on this  how do you create contact group in google people api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs I think you should specify a field `requestBody` in the call to `people.contactGroups.create`.

Try something like this:

```
const res = await people.contactGroups.create({
  requestBody: {
    "contactGroup": {
      "name": "HelloWorld"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, plugged it into the  code and walla,  respond with 200. thanks. like 100*10000 times, now i can move on..